# css block has zero height

Tags: html, css

I have a div `thumbnails` which floats a number of sub divs `cell`. Below that, I want to display another div `title`. Instead of displaying below, it is displaying in a new column to the right of `thumbnails`. Why ?

The `thumbnails` div is reporting zero height, although the actual `cell` divs are displaying properly.

Here is (I hope) the relevant part of my CSS

```
.thumbnails {display:block; margin-left:50px; margin-bottom:10px}

.cell {float:left; width:350px; height:350px;
       display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;
       z-index:0;}

.title {margin:auto; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; text-align:center; }
```

And, here's a snip of the html:

```
<body ...>
<div id="paintings">
  <div class=menu-bar>
    ...
  </div>

  <div class=title>
    ...
  </div>

  <div class=thumbnails>
    <div class=cell>
      ...
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <div class=title>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

NB: it's the second `title` div that doesn't display properly, because the height of the `thumbnails` div is zero.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Request to reopen: if someone has a zero-height div problem, they are not going to know to search for "clearfix". In other words, if you already knew you needed to add "clear:both" you wouldn't be searching for a solution. If people wish to maintain this question as duplicate, I suggest adding text to the other questions about zero-height divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set `clear:both` after `thumbnails tag`

```css
    .thumbnails {display:block; margin-left:50px; margin-bottom:10px}

    .cell {float:left; width:350px; height:350px;
           display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;
           z-index:0;}

    .title {margin:auto; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; text-align:center; }
    .clear{clear:both}
```

```html
    <body ...>
    <div id="paintings">
      <div class=menu-bar>
       sdfsdf
      </div>

      <div class=title>
        sdfsdf
      </div>

      <div class=thumbnails>
        <div class=cell>
          sdfsdf
        </div>
        sdfsdf
      </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
      <div class=title>
        <p>sdfsdf</p>
      </div>
      sdfsdf
      
    </body>
```